# is there a method that scan a string and add line before a repeated keyword index in java

Tags: java, string, function, position

`The woman wears black dress the sun is yellow the apple has circle shape the cat drinks milk

I want the output to be a string but like this

```
The woman wears black dress
the sun is yellow
the apple has circle shape
the cat drinks milk
```

each sentence in a different line

i tried with that code that give the index of the keyword but don't know where to go next that code print all indexes of the

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\output3.txt");
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line = buf.readLine();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    while(line != null){ 
      sb.append(line).append("\n"); 
      line = buf.readLine(); 
    }
    String fileAsString = sb.toString();
    System.out.println("Contents : " + fileAsString);
    String keyword="the";
    int index = fileAsString.indexOf(keyword);
    while (index >=0) {
        int sum=0;
        System.out.println("Index : "+index);}
```

Comment: But `is` also appears many times in your text, why isn't it moved at start of next line?

Comment: this is just a sample data the real data only one word is repeated

Comment: So your example is wrong. Please correct it to match description of problem you are facing.

Comment: In addition to what @Pshemo has suggested, also post whatever code you have tried.

Comment: thanks for the advice now i edited it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two steps

1. Split your sentence on repeated keyword
2. join your array of string on keyword with new line charecter

you can follow below code

```
public String splitSentenceOnRepeatedKyword(String input,String keyword) {
   
 // Split sentence on keyword
    String [] res = input.toLowerCase().split(keyword);
    
 // join array of String on keyword with new line
    return String.join("\n the",res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to split your string. A one liner using streams :

```
String str = "The woman wears black dress the sun is yellow the apple has circle shape the cat drinks milk";
    
String splited = Pattern.compile("(?=(?i)\\bThe\\b)")
                        .splitAsStream(str)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));

System.out.println(splited);
```